# Playa field within a Matrix field - not displaying results

Tags: matrix, playa

I'm trying to get information from a [Playa](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/playa) field within a [Matrix](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/matrix) field, and nothing is showing. It's a very simple task, and I can't see where I've made a mistake:

```
{model}<!--Matrix field-->
<div class="row details">
<div class="large-6 columns">
<img src="{model_image}" title="{model_title}" alt="{model_title}">
</div>
<div class="large-6 columns">
<p>{if "{model_production}"=="Yes"}In production.{if:else}Out of production.{/if}</p>
{if model_link}
<p>Best source for this model:<br>
<a href="{model_link}" title="{model_link}" target="_blank">{link_title}</a></p>{/if}
{if model_painter}<!--Playa field-->
<p>Example painted by {model_painter}{title}{/model_painter}</p>
{/if}
</div>
</div>
{/model}
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried the exp:playa:children tag in place of the fieldtype tag?

Comment: You could try the var_prefix parameter to make sure the variables are not in conflict with each other.

Answer (score 1):

One thing you could do is eliminate the conditional around the Playa field - like the entries loop, Playa won't output anything if no results are found. So you can do something like this instead:

```
{model_painter}
    <p>{if count == "1"}Example painted by{/if} {title}</p>
{/model_painter}
```

This may not have any bearing on why you're not seeing a result from your playa field, but it would simplify your loop just slightly.

Could there be a custom status at play that would be causing the playa field in the matrix to fail to return an entry for you?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your replies. The solution was to use {exp:playa:children field="model_painter" status="not closed"}

The channel I'm pulling data from is a Zoo Visitor members channel, and it requires the status="not closed" parameter.

Comment: can you show what your final code looked like? I'm having the same problem. Thanks

Comment: Sorry - missed this quesion! `{exp:playa:children field="official_models_painter" row_id="{row_id}" status="not closed"}
    <p><strong>Example painted by:</strong><br><a href="{site_url}players/profiles/{url_title}">{screen_name}</a></p>
    {/exp:playa:children}`